# Updating multiple projects using svn:externals

Tags: visual-studio, svn, tortoisesvn, visualsvn, visualsvn-server

**Overview**

I am using VisualSVN in Visual Studio, VisualSVN Server on Windows, and of course, TortoiseSVN. I wanted to know what the best method of sharing multiple projects over multiple solutions was, and if there was a better method.

**Layout**

My Repository kind of looks like this (not their real names):

```
Library.Common
Library.Web
Library.DB
Library.CMS
Customer1.Site
Customer2.Site
```

**Process**

To create a new site that contains common projects:

1. Create Repository in SVN-Server, e.g. "Customer3.Site"
2. Create Web site using Visual Studio 2008, named "Customer3.Site", VisualSVN used to commit to the repository created in step (1).
3. Edit properties of Customer3.Site and specify the necessary projects as svn:externals, e.g. "Library.Common", "Library.DB", etc.
4. Perform an update, to get these external projects, and add them to my solution in Visual Studio, add the necessary references to the Customer3.Site web project and hit build.

So far so good.

**The Problem**

All this works fine, I am happy that if I have to modify any of the core Library projects I can do so right in the same environment and commit them to the repository.  As more and more customer sites are built, I will then have to keep track of what I've done and remember to SVN Update and rebuild those sites which seems quite a long-winded task.

Is there a better way of doing this, a more best-practice solution?  Am I breaking any fundamental SVN laws by doing it this way?  I want to find a good solution that doesn't cost too much time and isn't overly complex either.

Answer (score 0):

I've been facing a similar issue ... I am setting up a base install package for WordPress, something we would use to quickly get a site setup, it contains the core of wordpress + a set of baseline plugins, both third party and custom ones we've created. Everything pretty much comes from SVN.

Different plugins have different versions/tags and to setup an svn external pointing to a specific tagged version per project would be a nightmare ... only to then have to go into each and every project and do a property adjustment and then an update.

What going to be implementing is a vendor branch with specific versions as needed. All I should then have to do is update the client sites, since they will always be pointing to the latest versions (under my control in the vendor branches).

As to your problem, and also in my case: I would probably write a commit script to update all projects automatically when something in the vendor branch is updated.